# How to declare a method that returns an instance of an interface

Tags: java

So I am a bit new to Java. I just got introduced to interfaces and i have to create a method that returns an instance of the interface `Chassis`

Below is the code:

```
public interface Chassis {
    public String Chassis = "Chassis";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        public String getChassisType() {
            return Chassis;
        }
```

The problem is, I keep getting error that abstract methods cannot have a body (as indicated by the blockquote) yet i had not declared my method as abstract.

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: You have a method declaration inside another method.  You need to define each method separately.

Comment: how exactly could i go about doing that? by declaring the getChassis type outside the interface?

Comment: You can't instantiate an interface. You can only instantiate its implementations.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems, You can't put a method inside another method, and you can't define a method like this in an interface in Java. In Java 8 you can do this

```
public interface Chassis {

    String Chassis = "Chassis";

    default String getChassisType(){
        return Chassis;
    }
}
```

I wouldn't define your `public static void main` inside an interface. While it is allowed now, most developers would find this confusing. See @Jürgen's answer, as this what most experienced developers would say I believe.

I would create another class like

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        // an anonymous subclass so you have something to create/call.
        System.out.println(new Chassis(){}.getChassisType());
    }
}
```

Comment: defining it like this creates an error which requires me to create a main.java class because main was defined as public

Comment: @MichaelM.  Correct, all public top level classes have to be in the own file. In a normal Java project you will have hundreds, if not thousands of files.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Couldn't agree more that this is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a kind of abstract. It cannot be instantiated, It can have only declaration of methods and attributes not definition. You can only implement it in a class,  if you do so in a class you must define all the methods which are  declared in the interface. A main method need to be defined in order to execute the program. So it should not be placed inside an interface. change your code like this below

```
public interface chassis
{ 
 String Chassis;
 public String chassis();
}
public class example implements chassis
{
 public String chassis()
 {
 Chassis="chassis";
 return Chassis; 
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
 System.out.println(new example().getChassisType());
 }
}
```

Comment: I have changed it @BrandonIbbotson

Comment: That's better, the 1 space tab still irks me a little bit though.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>This code would not work at all. A main method is only valid for classes, not for interfaces.</strike>

**EDIT:** as stated below the answer is not correct. But having a method inside a method still does not work. See the other answers.

Comment: In Java 8 you can add `main` to an interface, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: A main public static void main in an interface? Really??

Comment: I just tried it just to check and it works as you might expect o_O

Comment: I just tried this as well. OMG! Why?? Btw... Thanks for the info!

Comment: You can now add `public static` and `default` methods to interfaces, and `main` is one of the former.

Comment: I really was not aware of that.